moving website hosting to different hosting provider using same name servers (ns1.stackdns.com)
I am trying to move a client website from one web host to another. Both hosting providers use the same set of dns servers for hosting (ns1.stackdns.com,ns2.stackdns.com,ns3.stackdns.com,ns4.stackdns.com).
I have removed the website from 1st host. I didn't change the custom nameservers in domain control panel (as the set used by both providers is the same). nslookup shows "Query refused".
I have installed wordpress on the new web host. however wordpress site is not opening.
I have opened a ticket with new provider but haven't received reply from the web hosting support. What should I do? Please help.
Thanks,
Sohail

You probably have to follow up with the web provider. Otherwise, you probably need to provide more information for us - like what was the message you see when you tried to open Wordpress. Also, what does the nslookup says when you use a different name server like nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8

When I attempt to open Wordpress website, it says "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site." in firefox. nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8 gives Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4018:806::200e
142.250.181.174

When I attempt to query 8.8.8.8 using nslookup for the concerned domain, it says "*** dns.google can't find [mydomain].com: Server failed"
